# Finding GoogleAds link programmatically

Tags: java, url, google-ad-manager

I have a webpage such as http://venueh.com. I am viewing the source code and went over every element on the page with the F12 button on google chrome, but I cannot find how the links are generated on that page.

How do I find the URLs using Java code  on the page? The type of URL I am looking for is:

```
http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=C8NUlvWFHUsbGOYeZqwGdjYHwA_Lr1IgEwsWq9IABwI23ARABIJCOnAYoCFCkmMnc_v____8BYP2AiYHoA6ABzpL90gPIAQGpAsQJR2N3SbA-qAMBqgRgT9DQ66tuGiYxsVL0LulaaILQ7JRw2yx6yh7PDW1oKxNq6QW_-JPl9PQbltHrK5rVKLql3vSQvfU16dDA5gpxoh4Ki6_h8iZ6vBwUVwEOPS1CdyLclm8k1BCG5ShiUcfciAYBgAea7YIt&num=1&cid=5GjsnhKgZ6UggGWKakkVgPi0&sig=AOD64_1-c5uxNMC34FmNAjjl6humLnpx3A&adurl=https://www.canadianstage.com/Online/default.asp%3FdoWork::WScontent::loadArticle%3DLoad%26BOparam::WScontent::loadArticle::article_id%3D3ABD3282-8AF0-44F3-B30A-6F3A9CB98774%26BOparam::WScontent::loadArticle::promocode_access_code%3DVenus0906%26utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dcpc%26utm_term%3DVenus0906%26utm_content%3DVenus0906%26utm_campaign%3Dcanadian-stage-competitor-terms-venus0906-adwords&client=ca-dp-namedrive13_3ph_xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click, and Inspect element on Google chrome. I can see the link on the url you mentioned.

As the question has been changed:

If you are using any client side coding such as Javascript or jquery, you can search for the link for the particular anchor.

```
$('a[href*="googleadservices"]')
```

Comment: $('a[href*="googleadservices"]') and any other link showing that only displays on the inspect element on the http://venueh.com web page. Unless you are opening another page to view it, I can't do anything with that.

Comment: @Tyluur: Unless you are sure, what you really want to do with the data, I can't help you. Thanks